# SAS duration not appearing correctly in excel pivot

Tags: excel, sas, pivot

I currently have a SAS dataset that has "Production Time" formatted as numeric Time. (shows as hh:mm:ss). When I pull in a subset of the data, the duration shows correctly hh:mm:ss, however, when I try to use a pivot (external connection to the entire CSV file) to find the sum of hours on a particular day it displays hundreds of hours (996:00:00) when it should be approximately 8 hours worth (08:00:00). And not allowing me to "sum" because it's a date. Only allows me to "count".

Additionally, when I click into the value in the pivot table, it's treating it as a datetime (2/9/1900 12:00:00 AM) even though I've formatted it as HH:MM:SS in the value field settings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Those are Excel limitations not SAS limitations, if Excel won't add times you'll need to export your data differently.

Comment: What if you export the time as a character?

Comment: @Stu Sztukowski I've tried to export both as a character and numeric, both resulting in the same issue.

Comment: @Reeza how would you recommend I export the data?

Comment: I'd export it as a formula so there was no ambiguity. `=TIME(0,A2,0)`

Comment: @Reeza formatting it as a formula in SAS? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: I missed that you're exporting to CSV...that won't work in that case, only in ODS EXCEL most likely.

Comment: Really, you need to find out how Excel needs time data to be input and then once you have that figured out you can get SAS to output it however is needed.